# Break Points Flash When Debugging in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, visual-studio-debugging

I'm stuck on this weird behavior and was wondering if anyone else has run across this issue before.

I'm running the emulator for Windows Phone 8.1 and have a break point set at `public App()` which flashes and the emulator goes to the main screen. The break never gets hit and no output in regards to any error messages. I swipe to the installed app and try to run it again and the same thing happens.

Ideas?

Comment: Do you use the VS2013 Update4 or an older update?

Comment: I am running VS 2014 Update 4.

Comment: I tried creating a new project and added back on references like the original project and once I finished this, the same behavior exhibits.

So now i'll try creating a third project and add in the old itmes one at a time and try debugging each time I add new items to see what is causing the problem. Uggh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was causing the issue. The startup object didn't have a value in the project property section. Once I made a selection, the app was able to go in debug mode.